# Alert on DIV refresh with new website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get an alert  once the DIV is refreshed with the new Information/Website

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
    function changeURL(){
    var URL2add = "http://google.com";
    var user="1";

     $.ajax({
                url: 'myApi.php?user=' + user + '&url='+ URL2add, 
                success: function(html) {                    
                var newHTML = "<object id='webloader' data='" + html + "'></object>";
                $("#exweb").fadeOut(5, function () {
                $("#exweb").html(newHTML).fadeIn(50);

                // alert("done");

                               });
                        }
                });
    }
</script>
```

the way i have it now the alert pops up Before the Div is refreshed

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `complete` action of [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) function similar to what you are doing for [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/). In your above code, you can simply do it like this-

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'myApi.php?user=' + user + '&url='+ URL2add, 
            success: function(html) {                    
                var newHTML = "<object id='webloader' data='" + html + "'></object>";
                $("#exweb").fadeOut(500, function () {
                    $("#exweb").html(newHTML).fadeIn(5000, function() {
                        alert("done");
                    });
                });
            }
});
```

Another example with working fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/gug08249/

Comment: Can you please explain with some sample code? I don't understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @DynamiteMedia Yeah sure